# Postgresql Upgrade fails from version 11 to 12 with repmgr 4 to 5

Tags: postgresql

On Production server we have repmgr version 4 and upgraded it to version 5. Now doing upgrade of postgresql from 11 to 12. Getting error during the upgrade.

pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  could not find function "am_bdr_failover_handler" in file "/usr/lib/postgresql/12/lib/repmgr.so"
Command was: CREATE FUNCTION "repmgr"."am_bdr_failover_handler"(integer) RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE "c" STRICT
AS '$libdir/repmgr', 'am_bdr_failover_handler';

-- For binary upgrade, handle extension membership the hard way
ALTER EXTENSION "repmgr" ADD FUNCTION "repmgr"."am_bdr_failover_handler"(integer);

Any hint?

Comment: Perhaps try removing repmgr, upgrade postgres and then reinstall repmgr

Comment: Hi,                                                                                              
But document says different way. https://repmgr.org/docs/current/upgrading-and-pg-upgrade.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that repmgr versions are different for PostgreSQL 11 and PostgreSQL 12. Once I made it same, PostgreSQL upgrade 11 to 12 worked smoothly.